# Trouble with running code in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I know this has been asked many many times, but I am a complete beginner at Linux and I have never used it before this. I am trying to set up VSCode for the past hour or so, and now that I finally got the extensions working (did i?) I tried testing it out and it doesn't work. When I type couple basic lines of code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "It's not working" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

And when I try to run the code I get this:

> [Running] cd "/home/user/School/CPP Codes/" && g++ test.cpp -o test && "/home/user/School/CPP Codes/"test
>   /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
>   (.text+0x20): undefined reference to`main'
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>   [Done] exited with code=1 in 0.096 seconds

I read on some of the posts that I should add -o ?! But again I have 0 clue what that means or what I should do exactly. So any help would be insanely appreciated!

Comment: The build command looks right. Are you sure `test.cpp` is the right file?

Comment: Dear god now it works. When you said that i just closed the file and opened it again and it worked. Didn't change a letter. I was pulling my hair!!! What was that?

Comment: just a wild guess, maybe you did not save the file or the file was buffered somewhere... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ apart from that, your code and command is right as @LightnessRacesinOrbit mentioned

Comment: @skratchi.at Yes it indeed turned out I have to save the file after every iteration, which is slightly annoying.

Comment: If you don't save the file to disk, then when the compiler loads the file from disk it will be out of date. Although I'm a little surprised [the IDE doesn't save it for you when you hit 'build'](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_save-auto-save); I guess that's because of how the IDE and compiler are isolated in the case of VS Code. Disclaimer: I haven't used it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yeah well VSCode comes naked, and you have to install all the extensions including compilers etc. Thanks for the link! Turned auto save on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linker errors are indeed hard to debug. After some years you will get them a bit better. Basically the linker tells you, that he finds the file, but does not find your main. As i mentioned in my comment this could be

1. you did not safe the file
2. your file got buffer in any way

In my experience, vs code shows the status of saving a bit hidden. where the cross for closing the file is, there is a round dot.

Comment: Indeed it turns out I didn't save the file. One quick question:
How do i run the code in the terminal? When i run it it shows the code in the "output" window, but since i have to input some information it doesnt work

Comment: Command? I don't follow. I use the VS IDE at school which doesn't need any additional steps to set up, but since i have linux i use the vscode at home so I have no clue.

Comment: do you want to compile the code with a stand alone (not vs code connected) terminal or do you want to run your program in a terminal window?

Comment: In a terminal window in vscode. If that's what you meant

Comment: i run vs code under windwos, but should not make any difference. open a terminal in vs code `Terminal -> New Terminal`. then type `.\test`

Comment: this [LINK](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/index.htm) is for total beginners =)  maybe i can help you

Comment: Thanks for the link! Ill def check it out. But I just want to set up VSCode properly so i can practice coding. You said to type "\tests" into the terminal, nothing happens when i do that

Comment: Make shure you are in the same direktory as your binary is compiled to `/home/user/School/CPP Codes/`. with the command `pwd`. then check if your binary is in your dir with `ls`, which should be named `test` if i read your answer correctly. if all of that applies, you should be able to execute your program with `./test`.

Comment: The directory and binary all check out. If i type ".\test" with a dot it says
"Command '.test' not found". And if i use "\test" nothing happens. I enter it and nothing

Comment: make sure you are using the forward slash `/` NOT the backward slash

Comment: you wont make that mistake ever again =P and you are welcome^^